# C# / ASP - Exceptions throwing

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

Is it a good idea to throw exceptions like "ArgumentException" in ASP? I red some articles, and I know exceptions that I throw go to the Page_Error method. After this, execution is stuck here forever. How can I continue execution after Page_Error?

Or should I don't use throw and make something like this:

```
person.name = "blablabla";
if (person.NameValidatingError) Response.Write ("Ooops");
```

Comment: Exceptions are meaningless if there isn't someone who catches them

Comment: What is `.NameValidatingError`? Is it a boolean you're setting on the object?

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the argument to conform to some kind of validation rules and the passed in argument does not conform to them (and you can't recover), it is a good idea to throw an `ArgumentException` explaining why it was rejected.

You should, in `page_error` then redirect to an error page.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Error Page for your entire application and transfer all your exception to that page.

Comment: But I dont wanna 1 page for error, I need to put error messages inside html content w/o redirecting etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking a variable after setting something, you would encapsulate it in a try / catch block if you know it could throw an error.

Like this:

```
try
   person.name = "blablabla"
catch ex as YourExceptionType
   messagebox.show("There was an error in the foobar")
end try

... continue code here
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if we are talking about C# or Asp.Net but the matter is if it's a good practice throw exceptions. 
In General you should throw exception only when is strictly needed as the exception throwing can leads the performance(sometime even hide the stack-trace).
Another aspect is that an exception is something that you could not foresee perhaps when you were coding that feature but not something that you already know it could happen/avoid happening
I would suggest you to avoid throwing exception as much as possible then if it is requirement in your domain you may create an error page to redirect to every time you get an unmanaged exception.

Answer (score -1):

If the method can handle the error on its own without putting the code in an invalid state, then there is no need to throw an exception.

Otherwise, the method should throw an exception, leaving it up to the caller to decide if it knows how to handle the exception, or leave it uncaught.